# AWS RDS to PgAdmin Error saving properties Unable to connect to server: timeout expired

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

**Short description**: AWS RDS connecting server to PgAdmin 4, PostgreSQL 11

**Done**: I have done similar to [this](https://youtu.be/0GpQJM7w6M8?t=215) guy or to this [aws guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.PostgreSQL.html) but at the end when I click save it does not accept it for me. instead gives the following

**ERROR**:

```
Error saving properties 
Unable to connect to server: 
timeout expired
```

**What I have tried to solve the problem**:

- The instance is active it is 2 hours after creation
- I have also allowed to access database with outside of AWS database client "YES"
- this stack overflow answer does not deliver results https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903485/10270590 actually after refreshing my security group like the guide says my whole database disappeared
- I have home wi-fi so there are no corporate firewalls or any of those issues https://serverfault.com/q/705312/535406
- while reading the pervious server fault post I looked up my

  - RDS/Databases:  what was empty
  - RDS/Security groups: empty and I have this message:

```
Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. 
DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. 
Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances.
```

- I have tried which this question https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance that had 2 good answers but they gave the same error even after doing bot of the changes

  - https://serverfault.com/a/656119/535406
  - https://serverfault.com/a/880710/535406
- same as the above one - [AWS RDS Database show timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773330/aws-rds-database-show-timeout-error)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Edit inbound rules
Type have to be turned to: all traffic and my IP. than it works

[image]

Comment: You have not mentioned in AWS management console, how one can arrive at the above location.

Comment: AWS => Services => RDS => Databases => Choose your db.
In the "Security group role" section, choose the rule and edit as mentioned above.

Comment: It is important to note that a Serverless instance cannot be assigned a public IP, and so you cannot connect one outside of a VPC, as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.requirements.

Comment: is it safe to allow all traffic?

Comment: I've the same issue. Tried the above solution but didn't work for me.

Comment: one reason could be that when creating the db you should NOT select the default security group but choose the create new sg option. This worked fine for me,

Comment: Thanks a lot, after a lot of searching I got it right.

Comment: In the "Connectivity" section you have to ensure that the option "Publicly accessible" is enabled.